# opensips config file not working

Tags: voip, ubuntu-14.04, opensips

Opensips config file
Name : opensips.cfg
location :- /usr/local/etc/opensips

```
  #
# $Id$
#
# OpenSIPS residential configuration script
#     by OpenSIPS Solutions <team@opensips-solutions.com>
#
# This script was generated via "make menuconfig", from
#   the "Residential" scenario.
# You can enable / disable more features / functionalities by
#   re-generating the scenario with different options.#
#
# Please refer to the Core CookBook at:
#      http://www.opensips.org/Resources/DocsCookbooks
# for a explanation of possible statements, functions and parameters.
#


####### Global Parameters #########

debug=3
log_stderror=no
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0

fork=yes
children=4

/* uncomment the following lines to enable debugging */
#debug=6
#fork=no
#log_stderror=yes

/* uncomment the next line to enable the auto temporary blacklisting of
   not available destinations (default disabled) */
#disable_dns_blacklist=no

/* uncomment the next line to enable IPv6 lookup after IPv4 dns
   lookup failures (default disabled) */
#dns_try_ipv6=yes
/* comment the next line to enable the auto discovery of local aliases
   based on revers DNS on IPs */
auto_aliases=no


listen=udp:192.168.2.16:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME


disable_tcp=yes

disable_tls=yes


####### Modules Section ########

#set module path
mpath="/usr/local/lib64/opensips/modules/"

#### SIGNALING module
loadmodule "signaling.so"

#### StateLess module
loadmodule "sl.so"

#### Transaction Module
loadmodule "tm.so"
modparam("tm", "fr_timeout", 5)
modparam("tm", "fr_inv_timeout", 30)
modparam("tm", "restart_fr_on_each_reply", 0)
modparam("tm", "onreply_avp_mode", 1)

#### Record Route Module
loadmodule "rr.so"
/* do not append from tag to the RR (no need for this script) */
modparam("rr", "append_fromtag", 0)
#### MAX ForWarD module
loadmodule "maxfwd.so"

#### SIP MSG OPerationS module
loadmodule "sipmsgops.so"

#### FIFO Management Interface
loadmodule "mi_fifo.so"
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_name", "/tmp/opensips_fifo")
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_mode", 0666)


#### URI module
loadmodule "uri.so"
modparam("uri", "use_uri_table", 0)







#### MYSQL module
loadmodule "db_mysql.so"



#### USeR LOCation module
loadmodule "usrloc.so"
modparam("usrloc", "nat_bflag", "NAT")
modparam("usrloc", "db_mode",   0)

#### REGISTRAR module
loadmodule "registrar.so"
modparam("registrar", "tcp_persistent_flag", "TCP_PERSISTENT")

/* uncomment the next line not to allow more than 10 contacts per AOR */
#modparam("registrar", "max_contacts", 10)
                                              #### ACCounting module
loadmodule "acc.so"
/* what special events should be accounted ? */
modparam("acc", "early_media", 0)
modparam("acc", "report_cancels", 0)
/* by default we do not adjust the direct of the sequential requests.
   if you enable this parameter, be sure the enable "append_fromtag"
   in "rr" module */
modparam("acc", "detect_direction", 0)
modparam("acc", "failed_transaction_flag", "ACC_FAILED")
/* account triggers (flags) */
modparam("acc", "log_flag", "ACC_DO")
modparam("acc", "log_missed_flag", "ACC_MISSED")


#### AUTHentication modules
loadmodule "auth.so"
loadmodule "auth_db.so"
modparam("auth_db", "calculate_ha1", yes)
modparam("auth_db", "password_column", "password")
modparam("auth_db", "db_url",
        "mysql://root:root@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME
modparam("auth_db", "load_credentials", "")













####### Routing Logic ########

# main request routing logic

route{


        if (!mf_process_maxfwd_header("10")) {
                sl_send_reply("483","Too Many Hops");
                exit;
        }

        if (has_totag()) {
                # sequential request withing a dialog should
                # take the path determined by record-routing
                if (loose_route()) {

                        if (is_method("BYE")) {
                                setflag(ACC_DO); # do accounting ...
                                setflag(ACC_FAILED); # ... even if the transaction fails
                        } else if (is_method("INVITE")) {
                                # even if in most of the cases is useless, do RR for
                                # re-INVITEs alos, as some buggy clients do change route set
                                # during the dialog.
                                record_route();
                        }



                        # route it out to whatever destination was set by loose_route()
                        # in $du (destination URI).
                        route(relay);
                } else {

                        if ( is_method("ACK") ) {
                                if ( t_check_trans() ) {
                                        # non loose-route, but stateful ACK; must be an ACK after 
                                        # a 487 or e.g. 404 from upstream server
t_relay();
                                        exit;
                                } else {
                                        # ACK without matching transaction ->
                                        # ignore and discard
                                        exit;
                                }
                        }
                        sl_send_reply("404","Not here");
                }
                exit;
        }

        # CANCEL processing
        if (is_method("CANCEL"))
        {
                if (t_check_trans())
                        t_relay();
                exit;
        }

        t_check_trans();

        if ( !(is_method("REGISTER")  ) ) {

                if (from_uri==myself)

                {

                        # authenticate if from local subscriber
                        # authenticate all initial non-REGISTER request that pretend to be
                        # generated by local subscriber (domain from FROM URI is local)
                        if (!proxy_authorize("", "subscriber")) {
                                proxy_challenge("", "0");
                                exit;
                        }
                        if (!db_check_from()) {
                                                     sl_send_reply("403","Forbidden auth ID");
                                exit;
                        }

                        consume_credentials();
                        # caller authenticated

                } else {
                        # if caller is not local, then called number must be local

                        if (!uri==myself) {
                                send_reply("403","Rely forbidden");
                                exit;
                        }
                }

        }

        # preloaded route checking
        if (loose_route()) {
                xlog("L_ERR",
                "Attempt to route with preloaded Route's [$fu/$tu/$ru/$ci]");
                if (!is_method("ACK"))
                        sl_send_reply("403","Preload Route denied");
                exit;
        }

        # record routing
        if (!is_method("REGISTER|MESSAGE"))
                record_route();

        # account only INVITEs
        if (is_method("INVITE")) {

                setflag(ACC_DO); # do accounting
 }


        if (!uri==myself) {
                append_hf("P-hint: outbound\r\n"); 

                route(relay);
        }

        # requests for my domain

        if (is_method("PUBLISH|SUBSCRIBE"))
        {
                sl_send_reply("503", "Service Unavailable");
                exit;
        }

        if (is_method("REGISTER"))
        {

                # authenticate the REGISTER requests
                if (!www_authorize("", "subscriber"))
                {
                        www_challenge("", "0");
                        exit;
                }

                if (!db_check_to())
                {
                        sl_send_reply("403","Forbidden auth ID");
                        exit;
                }

                if (   0 ) setflag(TCP_PERSISTENT);

                if (!save("location"))
                                       sl_reply_error();

                exit;
        }

        if ($rU==NULL) {
                # request with no Username in RURI
                sl_send_reply("484","Address Incomplete");
                exit;
        }







        # do lookup with method filtering
        if (!lookup("location","m")) {
                if (!db_does_uri_exist()) {
                        send_reply("420","Bad Extension");
                        exit;
                }

                t_newtran();
                t_reply("404", "Not Found");
                exit;
        }



        # when routing via usrloc, log the missed calls also
        setflag(ACC_MISSED);
        route(relay);
}

route[relay] {
        # for INVITEs enable some additional helper routes
        if (is_method("INVITE")) {



                t_on_branch("per_branch_ops");
                t_on_reply("handle_nat");
                t_on_failure("missed_call");
        }



        if (!t_relay()) {
                send_reply("500","Internal Error");
        };
        exit;
}




branch_route[per_branch_ops] {
        xlog("new branch at $ru\n");
}


onreply_route[handle_nat] {

        xlog("incoming reply\n");
}


failure_route[missed_call] {
        if (t_was_cancelled()) {
                exit;
 }

        # uncomment the following lines if you want to block client 
        # redirect based on 3xx replies.
        ##if (t_check_status("3[0-9][0-9]")) {
        ##t_reply("404","Not found");
        ##      exit;
        ##}


}
```

using this config file i am unable to connect my Zoiper softphone.
it is showing SIP 408 Request Timeout

Note :-opensip ver 1.11
It is working fine when i am not using  authentication module.

Comment: will you post the error log for opensips.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to REGISTER and authenticate your phone, chances are the cause is external (script, hardware/software, etc.), rather than a OpenSIPS bug.

Please extract a network capture with *ngrep* or *wireshark*, and try to understand where the authentication is failing. You can post a link with the capture here if you cannot solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: I have generated the config file using menuconfig tool,have selected use_auth from residential config generator.

Comment: OpenSIPS is not even responding. Possible causes: bad listening interface (most likely) or some kind of firewall in the middle (less likely). Is OpenSIPS listening for UDP on 192.168.2.16:5060? What do the logs say? You should post this question on the users@opensips.org mailing list.

Comment: Yes,opensips is listening on 192.168.2.16:5060. when i m not including the auth module then i am able to make calls.

Comment: What do the OpenSIPS logs say? If possible, put OpenSIPS in debug mode, make a failed authenticated REGISTER, and share a link with the log file here. The script looks good.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have solved the problem, i have added
db_default_url="mysql://opensips:opensipsrw@localhost/opensips"
this line in config file.